# Pagination in YouTube API Version 2

Tags: php, youtube-api

I am  trying to fetch videos from the YouTube server based on my keywords, but when try to change the version 1 to version 2, it's not paginating.

I got following output from the YouTube server.

```
Search results
items found. Showing items to -1:
```

The following code I used to fetch the video from the YouTube server:

```
$feedURL = "http://gdata.youtube.com/feeds/api/videos?q={$vq}&v=2";
$sxml = simplexml_load_file($feedURL);
```

The following code for the pagination:

```
require_once 'Pager/Pager.php';
  $params = array(
      'mode'       => 'Jumping',
      'perPage'    => $i,
      'delta'      => 5,
      'totalItems' => $total,
  );
  $pager = & Pager::factory($params);
  $links = $pager->getLinks();
```

Please anybody help me to resolve this issue.

Comment: What's the complete URL that you use? (what's in your `$vq` variable?)

Comment: http://gdata.youtube.com/feeds/api/videos?q=boat&v=2

Comment: $vg=boat, that i have already mention in the above link, please check.

Answer (score 1):

This is really a black box, because I don't know what `Pager.php` is doing. It's not a standard part of any client library I know of.

The way paging works in the GData API v2 is described at a protocol level at https://developers.google.com/youtube/2.0/reference#Paging_through_Results. You can point the author of `Pager.php` to that if they're unsure how they're supposed to handle things.

In general, you might find things easier if you use the Zend PHP GData client library. If you do, there's a description of how paging works when using the library at https://developers.google.com/youtube/2.0/developers_guide_php#Pagination